# kern.log bandwidth and syslog filling up with bandwidth lines

Tags: ubuntu, log-files

I'm using Ubuntu 11.04 and my kern.log, bandwidth, and syslog files are filling(And completely consuming my hard drive) with this stuff

```
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.503932] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=184.106.76.80 DST=129.42.208.185 LEN=187 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=12744 PROTO=TCP SPT=13839 DPT=30051 WINDOW=2003 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.505102] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=184.106.76.80 DST=92.28.250.158 LEN=155 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=28110 PROTO=TCP SPT=13743 DPT=13809 WINDOW=65535 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.505133] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=184.106.76.80 DST=78.86.165.146 LEN=155 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=64959 PROTO=TCP SPT=13743 DPT=34341 WINDOW=9261 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.505158] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=184.106.76.80 DST=82.9.127.44 LEN=155 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=11111 PROTO=TCP SPT=13743 DPT=53016 WINDOW=3593 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.510378] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=40:40:1b:3e:06:6a:c8:4c:75:f5:eb:3f:08:00 SRC=86.27.137.140 DST=184.106.76.80 LEN=1300 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=9384 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53925 DPT=13770 WINDOW=258 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.510425] BANDWIDTH_OUT:IN= OUT=eth0 SRC=184.106.76.80 DST=86.27.137.140 LEN=40 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=6076 PROTO=TCP SPT=13770 DPT=53925 WINDOW=4055 RES=0x00 ACK URGP=0 
Apr 18 20:20:23 main kernel: [1886527.510445] BANDWIDTH_IN:IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=40:40:1b:3e:06:6a:c8:4c:75:f5:eb:3f:08:00 SRC=86.27.137.140 DST=184.106.76.80 LEN=610 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=116 ID=9385 DF PROTO=TCP SPT=53925 DPT=13770 WINDOW=258 RES=0x00 ACK PSH URGP=0
```

It seems that the most I can setup log rotation for is daily, and that doesn't seem to be enough, especially if it's backing them up etc.
So I'm not looking for a "use log rotation to fix your problem" kind of answer, I'm looking for a way to get rid of these messages. I never had them before, and they are a nuisance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have something that running that logs into syslog, if that logging is not needed, you should either disable it or maybe write into a separate file and rotate that instead.

I think it's Shorewall that does that, so look into there to disable logging
[Shorewall FAQs](http://www.shorewall.net/FAQ.htm#Logging)

EDIT:

try following howto:

[IptablesHowTo - Community Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo)

Comment: I don't have shorewall installed, must be comming from somewhere else?

Comment: I assume something is causing this, just wondering if anyone had any ideas what it could be.

Comment: ok, then must be something else, could be shorewall, pfsense, untangle or firewall of some sort, I can't give you exact answer without seeing your system and since you provided so little information I can only guess..

Comment: Yeah, if none of those are installed with Ubuntu, I don't have them. Only type of monitoring I have is Nagios and DenyHosts.

Comment: this isn't monitoring tool, it's most likely a firewall ...  iptables?

Comment: Run the command `iptables --list -n -v`.  I suspect you will see your log source there.  After that you simply need to find what is adding the rules.

Comment: Cool I'll try that out.

Comment: iptables -L -n -v | grep -i log

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MX7QbL7f

Comment: http://pastebin.com/S5pZknYB

Comment: Respectively. Make any sense?

Comment: so there you go, you have a rule that logs everything, comment that rule out restart your firewall and you're done!

Comment: I'm not sure where to find it heh

Comment: try /etc/iptables.rules on CentOS/REDHAT its' in /etc/sysconfig/iptables, try do locate iptables

Comment: I just updated my main answer w/ likn to iptableshowto for ubuntu, you should be able to take it from there...

Answer (score 3):

This fixed my issue, from Kongen! at linuxquestions.org ...

In webmin under Networking -> Bandwidth Monitoring click "Turn Off Monitoring"

It removes "the kern.=debug -/var/log/bandwidth" from syslog.conf

It's a good idea if your are using the system as fileserver.

Not only will /var/log/bandwidth fill up your disk but syslogd and klogd will use a lot of CPU when you move big files to or from the system.

References: -

http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/mandriva-30/var-log-problem-it%27s-filling-up-at-lightspeed-437351/page2.html

Answer (score 0):

See what you have at `/etc/shorewall/start` maybe have something pretty similar to this:

```
run_iptables -I INPUT -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN: --log-level debug 
run_iptables -I FORWARD -i eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_IN: --log-level debug 
run_iptables -I FORWARD -o eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT: --log-level debug 
run_iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth0 -j LOG --log-prefix BANDWIDTH_OUT: --log-level debug
```

If so, delete it!  If you aren't using Shorewall see your `iptables` and delete those lines.